# Fancybox iframe, shows the iframe, then go to url?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i want to show a Vimeo video in an iframe using fancybox.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancyvarious").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

the link:

```
<a class="fancyvarious fancybox.iframe" href="http://vimeo.com/videoID"><img src="linkurl.jpg" alt="" width="950" height="400" /></a>
```

When I click on the image, it shows the iframe, but then it goes to the url... I only want to show the iframe.

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/

```
<a href="iframe.html" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Iframe</a>

<!--iframe.html-->
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/33698394?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="http://vimeo.com/33698394">The Love Competition</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user6989541">Brent Hoff</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".fancyvarious").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
// fancybox initialisation here...
```